# send message to webpage from chrome extension onInstalled

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I want to detect that Extension Installation (for Chrome, Mozilla, Safari) as soon as it is Installed.
I started with Chrome and my 
My Chrome's version is **52.0.2743.116 (64-bit)**

I tried posting message from chrome's content_script after adding addEventListner in my webpage,

but it only works after I reload the page once extension is Installed.
I don't want to reload the page.

I searched and got around "**onInstalled**" method in chrome Extension, so I tried sending message from background.js to content_script when 'onInstalled' event is reached

background.js

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function(details) {
console.log('installed');
chrome.tabs.query({ currentWindow : true}, function(tabs) {
    tabs.forEach(function(tab) {
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, { action : "Installed"},function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        });
    });
  });
});
```

content_script.js

```
// I also tried chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener (function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log('got message at content script');
 window.postMessage( { type: 'installed', text: 'true' }, "*" );
});
```

webpage js

```
 window.addEventListener( "message", function(event) {

    console.log(event.data.type);
});
```

manifest.js has "tabs" in permissions

I got undefined as the response in background.js and I never reached content_script's consoles, so it was not able to post message onInstalled

then I tried

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: "content_script.js"});
```

which did the trick, and I do not need to reload the page now.
but I am still curious why background.js was not able to send message to content_script.
Is it because of the url "chrome://extensions" which is not allowed in matched or something else? and if it is is the url, is there a work around?

Comment: Content scripts declared in manifest.json are executed automatically only during page load. You'll have to inject them manually with chrome.tabs.executeScript into matching tabs. I remember several question that might be used to dupehammer this one, but right now I wasn't able to find one.

Comment: Thanks @wOxxOm but I think I have seen a lot of extensions which do not require page Load or browser restart after installation, so are they all using executeScript, as I said above?or is there any better way do that? and why am I not able to send message from background.js to content script.js am I missing something?

Comment: although I have also found many questions but none answers my all queries

Comment: I thought and still think I've covered all of your questions with my comment. Now I'm not sure what to write in an answer. Someone else might have a better idea.

Comment: thanks @wOxxOm for your effort, I really appreciate,
I just need to know what was stopping me to send message from background to content_script.Let's see if someone else have answer for this.Thanks a lot btw

Comment: You've confused me even more. `Content scripts declared in manifest.json are executed automatically only during page load.` is the reason.

Comment: ohh is that why I was not able to send message to content script, on "onInstalled" . got it now. sorry for creating the mess. Thanks a lot :)